# Train test split in `r`'s `caret` package

Tags: r, r-caret

I'm getting familiar with `r`'s `caret` package, but, coming from other programming language, it thorougly confused me.

What I want to do now is a fairly simple machine learning workflow, which is:

1. Take a training set, in my case the iris dataset
2. Split it into a training and test set (a 80-20 split)
3. For every `k` from `1` to `20`, train the `k` nearest neighbor classifier on the training set
4. Test it on the test set

I understand how to do the first part, since `iris` is already loaded. Then, the second part is done by calling

```
a <- createDataPartition(iris$Species, list=FALSE)
training <- iris[a,]
test <- iris[-a,]
```

Now, I also know that I can train the model by calling

```
library(caret)
knnFit <- train()
knnFit <- train(Species~., data=training, method="knn")
```

However, this will result in `r` already performing some optimisation on the parameter `k`. Of course, I can limit what values of `k` the method should try, with something like

```
knnFit <- train(Species~., data=training, method="knn", tuneGrid=data.frame(k=1:20))
```

which works just fine, but it still doesn't to exactly what I want it to do. This code will now do, for each `k`:

1. take a bootstrap sample from the `test`.
2. Asses the performance of the `k`-nn method using the given sample

What I want it to do:

1. For each `k`, train the model **on the same train set which I constructed earlier**
2. Asses the performance **on the same test set which I constructed earlier.

So I would need something like

```
knnFit <- train(Species~., training_data=training, test_data=test, method="knn", tuneGrid=data.frame(k=1:20))
```

but this of course does not work.

I understand I should do something with the `trainControl` parameter, but I see its possible methods are:

```
"boot", "boot632", "cv", "repeatedcv", "LOOCV", "LGOCV", "none"
```

and none of these seems to do what I want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, this can be done all within caret using LGOCV (Leave-group-out-CV = repeated train/test split) and setting the training percentage `p = 0.8` and the repeats of the train/test split to `number = 1` if you really want just one model fit per `k` that is tested on a testset. Setting `number` > 1 will repeatedly assess model performance on `number` different train/test splits.

```
data(iris)
library(caret)
set.seed(123)
mod <- train(Species ~ ., data = iris, method = "knn", 
             tuneGrid = expand.grid(k=1:20),
             trControl = trainControl(method = "LGOCV", p = 0.8, number = 1,
                                      savePredictions = T))
```

All predictions that have been made by the different models on the test set are in `mod$pred` if `savePredictions = T`. Note `rowIndex`: These are the rows that have been sampled into the test set. Those are equal for all different values of `k`, so the same training/test sets are used every time.

```
> head(mod$pred)
    pred    obs rowIndex k  Resample
1 setosa setosa        5 1 Resample1
2 setosa setosa        6 1 Resample1
3 setosa setosa       10 1 Resample1
4 setosa setosa       12 1 Resample1
5 setosa setosa       16 1 Resample1
6 setosa setosa       17 1 Resample1
> tail(mod$pred)
         pred       obs rowIndex  k  Resample
595 virginica virginica      130 20 Resample1
596 virginica virginica      131 20 Resample1
597 virginica virginica      135 20 Resample1
598 virginica virginica      137 20 Resample1
599 virginica virginica      145 20 Resample1
600 virginica virginica      148 20 Resample1
```

There's no need to construct train/test sets manually outside of caret unless some kind of nested validation prodedure is desired. You can also plot the validation-curve for the different values of `k` by `plot(mod)`.

Comment: Looks like this is what I wanted, yes. Thank you!

Comment: I just love the way `caret` makes the code so clean. Of course, one pays for this succinct syntax by having to understand the workflow at a higher level and this can be intimidating to the beginner. However, it pays off handsomely later when you want to get a lot done quickly.

Comment: I find it easier to write my own "caret" type functions.  Much more fun and I have better control over how the cross validation and parameter optimization works.

I've noticed folks will blindly kick off caret runs with 15 different ML types with default parameters hoping to pin the tail on the donkey.  Instead they will end up with 15 poor models and no understanding of why they see bad performance. 

My advice? Learn a few modeling techniques (glmnet, xgboost, RF) really well to the point to where you are writing your own CV scripts and you will have a much better chance at succeeding

Answer (score 6):

Please read through the [caret website](http://topepo.github.io/caret/index.html)  to see how everything works. Or read the book "Applied Predictive Modeling" written by Max Kuhn for more info on how caret works.

Roughly speaking, trainControl contains a diverse set of parameters for the train function, like cross-validation settings, metrics to apply (ROC / RMSE), sampling, preprocessing, etc.

In train you can set additional settings like grid searches. I extended your code example so it works. Make sure to check how createDataPartition works, because the default setting splits the data in half.

```
library(caret)

a <- createDataPartition(iris$Species, p = 0.8, list=FALSE)
training <- iris[a,]
test <- iris[-a,]

knnFit <- train(Species ~ ., 
                data = training, 
                method="knn",  
                tuneGrid=data.frame(k=1:20))

knn_pred <- predict(knnFit, newdata = test)
```

**EDIT based on comment:**

What you want is not possible with one train object. Train will use the tunegrid to find the best k and use that outcome in the finalModel. This finalModel will be used for making predictions.

If you want to have an overview of all k's you might not want to use caret's train function but write a function for yourself. Maybe something like below. Note that knn3 is a knn-model from caret.

```
k <- 20
knn_fit_list <- list()
knn_pred_list <- list()

for (i in 1:k) {
  knn_fit_list[[i]] <- knn3(Species ~ ., 
                            data = training, 
                            k = i)
  knn_pred_list[[i]] <- predict(knn_fit_list[[i]], newdata = test, type = "class")

}
```

knn_fit_list will contain all the fitted models for the specified number of k. knn_pred_list will contain all the predictions.

Comment: I'm sorry if my question was a bit unclear, but I don't think this answers it. I understand the tuneGrid parameters, which is why I used it in my example code. What I want is to have a code similar to yours, but one that would return a prediction **for every** value of `k` in the training set. I hope my explanation made it clearer.