# Split the data in R, split into percentage

Tags: r, percentage

I have a dataset corresponding to different types datasets. Then how it is possible to calculate case.

Data should be split into one case: 1) **First Case** -  15% of train data & 5% test

How to write it correctly?

Comment: Check `?createDataPartition` from `caret`

Comment: can you write this example? table name is dt_raw, don,t know about the syntax..

Comment: You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35718350/train-test-split-in-rs-caret-package)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without [createDataPartition](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-81/topics/createDataPartition), an easy way will be as follows.

Suppose you want `train_prop` as training set and `test_prop` as test set from the dataset `my_dataset`. Ideally, their sum will be `1`, or `1-val_prop`, but here you want 15% and 5% for some reason. So you'll need 0.15 and 0.05 respectively.

```
indices <- sample(x = rep.int(x = c(0, 1, 2),
                  times = round(nrow(my_dataset) * c(1 - train_prop - test_prop, train_prop, test_prop))))
train_set <- my_dataset[indices == 1,]
test_set <- my_dataset[indices == 2,]
```

Comment: Sure! Am really sorry about that. I wanted to show you privately screenshot and a code. To ask you about this.. Am just a beginner...